# Angular 11 tsconfig Path Aliases not Recognized

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, aliases, angular11

I am working with Angular 11 and trying to use short imports like `import {smthg} from '@common'` instead of `import {smthg} from '../../../common'`

But I always get errors in IDEA: `TS2307: Cannot find module '@common' or its corresponding type declarations.`

And same error in console when trying to compile .ts files (`ng serve`)

Interestingly, when I add `/index` to the import, then IDEA stops cursing, but the error does not disappear in the console

```
myAngularProject
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   tsconfig.app.json
│   angular.json    
│
└───src
    │   main.ts
    │   index.html
    │
    └───app
        │  
        └───common
        │
        └───features
```

tsconfig.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["app/common/*"],
      "@features/*": ["app/features/*"],
      "@platform/*": ["app/platform/*"],
      "@env": ["environments/environment"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

IDEA error:
[image: idea error]

console tsc error:
[image]

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 14.2.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
```

Comment: The Angular compiler doesn't support `paths` as far as I am aware. Definitely annoying...

Comment: thanks for this terrible news (

looks like the truth.

well, it seems the only way is to give up angular CLI and use webpack.

Comment: I would have recommended that approach a year or so ago, but there is such a plethora of documentation that presumes the CLI as well as tooling built on top of it, such as the Ionic CLI, that it is a decision you should make circumspectly. I'm not saying it's the wrong one, as I particularly hate so many layered tooling abstractions that don't let you get at the internals when you need them, but consider carefully. Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it turned out that the angular engine allows creating aliases for paths based on what is specified in the "paths" in tsconfig.

But in order to be able to access both the subfolders of the module and what is exported from the index.ts at the top level of the module, you need to specify "paths" like this:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["app/common/*"],
      "@common": ["app/common/index.ts"]
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using VS Code and had unrecognized paths before applying this fix, you may need to also restart VS Code to clear the Linting errors.

Comment: thanks but its not working in angular 12 :/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I was trying to **migrate a project made with Angular 10** to Angular 11, coping the `./src/app` folder, but that didn't work...

But in a **new project**, I got the path aliasing working in that way:

- Update your angular cli:

```
PS C:\Projects> npm uninstall --g @angular/cli
PS C:\Projects> npm i --g @angular/cli
```

- Create a new project, setting the [strict mode](https://angular.io/strict) to `true`:

```
PS C:\Projects> ng new <<name-project>>
PS C:\Projects> cd <<name-project>>
```

- When the CLI ends, edit `tsconfig.app.json` as follows:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
        "types": [],

        // ADD THIS ↓↓↓
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@tool/*": [ "src/app/tool/*" ],
            "@models/*": [ "src/app/models/*" ],
            "@services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ],
            "@components/*": [ "src/app/components/*" ],
            "@interfaces/*": [ "src/app/interfaces/*" ]
        }
        // ADD THIS ↑↑↑
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

- ...and `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],

        // ADD THIS ↓↓↓
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@tool/*": [ "src/app/tool/*" ],
            "@models/*": [ "src/app/models/*" ],
            "@services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ],
            "@components/*": [ "src/app/components/*" ],
            "@interfaces/*": [ "src/app/interfaces/*" ]
        }
        // ADD THIS ↑↑↑
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

- ...and finally, edit `tsconfig.spec.json` as follows:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
        "types": [
            "jasmine"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@tool/*": [ "src/app/tool/*" ],
            "@models/*": [ "src/app/models/*" ],
            "@services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ],
            "@components/*": [ "src/app/components/*" ],
            "@interfaces/*": [ "src/app/interfaces/*" ]
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its not working for Angular 12.1.4

Comment: What helped me was to set it like ```"@tool/*": [ "src/app/tool/*" ]``` instead of ```"@tool/*": [ "app/tool/*" ]```, adding the 'src' part of the path made it work.

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me in Angular 13, Don't miss the dot *(.)* in each path value.

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "./src/app/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "./src/environments/*"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to restart your code editor to make sure it's not a problem with your linter.

I had similar problem and in my case configs were correct, though I didn't know that at that time due to the lack of experience so I kept on trying different solutions I could find. It turned out the problem was with the linter not being able to see config changes (added path definitions) until IDE restart.

Comment: `If nothing helps` You mean after trying these solutions? Because if you did try them, then it's likely that this is what fixed the issue -after restarting the editor-, not just magically the fact of restarting it. Please add details to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Path aliases are not longer supported in newer versions**

But you can do this now to directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add `baseUrl` to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

And now you can directly import stuff relative to the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

**This worked for me!**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the path aliasing was actually working, but I was missing a .ts file in the folder, so the types were not recognized.  Same error, though:
"Cannot find module @app or its corresponding type declarations"